# How to compare DateTime in django template in Oneweek

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use different stylesheet in django template if the time since publish is less than 7 days.

but Its not works.
please help me to make code works

model.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={
            'id':self.id
            })

    @property
    def less_than_week(self):
        if self.created.datetime.date + datetime.timedelta(days=7) <=   datetime.date.today():
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

template.html

```py
{% if post.created.date.less_than_week %}
   <h1>sample test</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please post the proper content of the `model.py`.

Comment: @funnydman thx!!updated